# Autosys Job failing due to underlying script not being exited

Tags: shell, unix, automation, autosys

I have an Autosys Job, which calls a wrapper script, which in turn calls a script which starts up a server and keeps running. 
Now the problem i am facing is that once the job starts , it keeps on waiting for the exit signal or script to exit, but being unable to find so sends the job into a FAILED state. 
Can anyone provide a workaround for this?

For demo : 
lets say i have autosys job :A

wrapper script as  : W.sh
Main restart script : serverrestart.sh

A
|---W.sh
      |---serverrestart.sh ( Always running )

Comment: what you want ...do you want kill the script..then you can use ps -ef to find that your job is running ..grep it with name and kill it..

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the AutoSys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.